# How to use WMI to add an IP route?

Tags: c++, networking, wmi

I need to add a route into the IP4 routing table on windows xp.

However, the Win32_IP4RouteTable class seems to only be able to query existing routes.

Basically I need the same functionality as:

```
route ADD 192.168.127.254 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.10
```

Is it possible to use WMI to add an entry into the IP4 routing table?

Could I use CreateProcess instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need solution on WMI only? I usually use [IPHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366073(VS.85).aspx). Specifically, you need [CreateIpForwardEntry function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365860(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: +1 Magic, thanks.  I'd forgotten about IPHelper and I'd actually prefer to use it because all that COM WMI code makes me feel quesy.  Now, I don't know what the S.O. etiquette here is - you've solved my problem but not answered the question!

Comment: Sod it, you solved the problem I'll accept it as the answer.  It doesn't seem like there's any other answers forthcoming anyway!